# Creating a new series for a Pandas data frame with boolean values but a non boolean index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to add a new series to my DataFrame using the .loc method as shown below

```py
EM['Starting'] = EM.loc[(['Program_Start_Date']==Trimester_Start_Date)]
```

However I am receiving the below error and have not been able to figure out how to fix it

```py
KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'
```

The data looks like this and I have Trimester date equal to 2022-05-30, so I should be getting results.

```
    Program_Start_Date Course_Withdrawn_Date Program_Withdrawal_Date
0           2022-05-30                  None                    None   
1           2022-05-30                  None                    None   
2           2022-05-30                  None                    None   
3           2022-05-30                  None                    None   
4           2022-05-30                  None                    None   
..                 ...                   ...                     ...   
543         2021-02-01                  None                    None   
544         2021-02-01                  None                    None   
545         2019-05-27            2022-08-18                    None   
546         2019-05-27            2022-08-18                    None   
547         2019-05-27            2022-08-18                    None
```

I expected that I would get a simple
True
True
True
True
... etc

as my results and have tried a few different methods creating a series but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to use `.loc()` with a condition, so it's returning True or False. And that doesn't work with `.loc()` unless the index is also True/False.

What I think you might be trying to do is filter the dataframe, which would look something like:

```
filter = [x==y for x,y in zip(EM.Program_Start_Date, EM.Trimester_Start_Date)]
EM_new = EM[filter]
```

The "filter" variable is a list of True/False that is passed into EM to select which rows make it into EM_new.

Hope that helps! If so, please upvote and accept my solution. =D